# Update relationship / payload with the Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am new to Neo4j and Neo4jClient. I am trying to update an existing relationship. Here is how I created the relationship.

```
var item2RefAddedBefore = _graphClient.CreateRelationship((NodeReference<Item>)item2Ref,
                new AddedBefore(item1Ref, new Payload() { Frequency = 1 }));
```

For this particular use case, I would like to update the Payload whenever the Nodes and relationship already exist. I am using Cypher mostly with the Neo4jClient.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `IGraphClient` signature:

```
void Update<TRelationshipData>(RelationshipReference<TRelationshipData> relationshipReference, Action<TRelationshipData> updateCallback)
    where TRelationshipData : class, new();
```

Like this:

```
graphClient.Update(
    (RelationshipReference<Payload>)item2RefAddedBefore,
    p => { p.Foo = "Bar"; });
```

**Update:** The syntax is a little awkward right now, where `CreateRelationship` only returns a `RelationshipReference` instead of a `RelationshipReference<TData>` but `Update` requires the latter, so you need to explicitly cast it. To be honest, we probably won't fix this any time soon as all of the investment for both Neo4j and Neo4jClient is going towards doing mutations via Cypher instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting errors. When I use this. _graphClient.Update<Payload>(item2RefAddedBefore, p => { p.Frequency = 1; }); I get this error ---- Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'ProjectNamespace.Form1.Payload'

Comment: The second error is Error 6 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Neo4jClient.RelationshipReference' to 'Neo4jClient.NodeReference<ProjectNamespace.Form1.Payload>'